# Automorphism groups of different fiber functors isomorphic?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

If I have a field extension $K/k$, a Tannakian category $\mathcal{C}$ over $k$, and two fiber functors $$\omega_1, \omega_2: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \text{Vec}_K$$ then are the two resulting automorphism group schemes isomorphic?

Comment: The answer is apparently "no", because of "inner forms". I will happily elaborate this into an answer upon request.

Comment: I would like to read your answer if you are still willing to do so.